# html5 video element - how can I get its name

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am writing an html5 video play-list based on [video.js](http://videojs.com/) and need to display the name of the current video. While I can easily get some meta-data such as the clip's duration using the js API, the name is no where to be found. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If with the name you mean the file name (only name you can extract from the file itself), you can verify the src attribute of the  tag. Remember to remove the URL part and keep only what's after the last '/'.

Otherwise you must send the name to the client side (maybe using [microdata](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)?).

Comment: sure it is easy to manually add a 'name' attr in. But in many cases, the name is just right there, in the src name, why should developers add an extra attr just for that? It is unbelievable that the video's name is treated so lightly

Comment: It makes sense to me, filenames might be treated in many ways and keeping the full name in it might be a pain in the a** resulting in huge names and such. Still, if it fits you, then you've got your solution, get the src attribute, remove everything until the last '/' char and there you go :)